# Failed to produce PDF file upon submitting Google form

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a function where upon submitting Google form, it will generate a PDF based on template document. However I still got an error where it says `error in line 2 e.namedvalue(e)` when I try to run the script.

```js
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info);
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1BSBIOPWFoc7o2nbX8XT23C85_pBq02VE");
  const tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1xSl7VhVwHAmIcVOdXVUlzwZcZ27q3hqU");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1vc7rTRU88LDF07hJs5Waf4OIWy2pAeoFNkB8UBpDnqI");
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempfolder);
  const opendoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId())
  const body = opendoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{dor}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{fn}", info['Name ( Nama )'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{nric}", info['NRIC/ID/PASSPORT ( No kad pengenalan/pasport )'][0]);

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name ( Nama )'][0] + " " + info['Timestamp'][0]);
}
```

Comment: Hosw do you run this function, have you installed afterFormSubmit as an installable trigger?

Comment: yes... already put the trigger afterformsubmit.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. [You can find the issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/196100674). To increase its priority, click the star (☆) on the left of the title.